# Create GCP service account and store service account key in secret manager in terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

```js
resource "google_service_account" bq_test{
    account_id = "ei-cs-test"
    display_name = "SA"
    project = "dev01-ein"
}

resource "google_service_account_key" "sa_key"{
    service_account_id = google_service_account.bq_test.name
    public_key_type = "TYPE_X509_PEM_FILE"
}

resource "google_secret_manager_secret" "secret-basic" {
  secret_id = "test-sa-ad-sec-id"

  labels = {
    label = "my-label"
  }
  replication {
    automatic = true
  }
  project = "-dev01-ein"
}

resource "google_secret_manager_secret_version" "admin-password" {
  secret = "test-sa-ad"
  secret_data = base64decode(google_service_account_key.sa_key.private_key)
}
```

Im trying to create a service account with service account key and store it in secret manager but I get the error.

```
Error: Error creating SecretVersion: googleapi: got HTTP response code 404 with body: <!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: What terraform version are you using? have you tried this Github link? https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google

Comment: Enable Terraform debugging via `TF_LOG` https://www.terraform.io/internals/debugging Post the REDACTED log in your question.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Are you aware that your key data will be in plain text in the TFstate?

Comment: Please may you explain the need to store SA key in Secret manager ? As Guillaume Blaquiere said, if you not encrypt your TFState file, the key will be visible in clear text into the file.

Comment: Is this not a recommended approach? Even though key will be visible in state file , as long as state file is stored safely - we should be good right? Is there a better recommended approach ?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you are trying to encrypt some sensitive information. I will recommend that you use Google KMS encryption and decryption. Thereby your secrets will be encrypted as secret.auto.tfvars.encrypted and you can also decrypt the cyphertext in the same local repository for example as secrets.auto.tfvars.

You can use this script below:

```html
$ echo -n my-secret-password | gcloud kms encrypt \
> --project my-project \
> --location us-central1 \
> --keyring my-key-ring \
> --key my-crypto-key \
> --plaintext-file - \
> --ciphertext-file - \
> | base64
CiQAqD+xX4SXOSziF4a8JYvq4spfAuWhhYSNul33H85HnVtNQW4SOgDu2UZ46dQCRFl5MF6ekabviN8xq+F+2035ZJ85B+xTYXqNf4mZs0RJitnWWuXlYQh6axnnJYu3kDU=
```

An example here will give you a better clue:

- https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/data-sources/kms_secret#example-usage
- https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/encrypt-decrypt

And don't forget to reference the encrypted ciphertext in your resource definitions:

Answer (score 0):

```html
resource "google_service_account" bq_test{
    account_id = "ei-cs-test"
    display_name = "SA"
    project = ""
}

resource "google_service_account_key" "sa_key"{
    service_account_id = google_service_account.bq_test.name
    public_key_type = "TYPE_X509_PEM_FILE"
}

resource "google_secret_manager_secret" "secret-basic" {
  secret_id = "secret-version"

  labels = {
    label = "my-label"
  }

  replication {
    automatic = true
  }
  project = ""
}

resource "google_secret_manager_secret_version" "admin-password" {
  secret = google_secret_manager_secret.secret-basic.id
  secret_data = base64decode(google_service_account_key.sa_key.private_key)
}
```

The mistake was on google_secret_manager_secret_version the secret was not referenced properly, therefore it was not working, try the above code it will work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).